# How to apply text modifications to bash special variables

Tags: bash, variables, data-conversion, capitalize

I have bash script that takes input arguments using bash special variables like $1, $2 etc.

I want to apply some text modification using `sed` on $2 and want to transfer the end result to $2. How can I achieve this??

Alternatively, I just want to format the text inside $2 into a capitalised manner i.e. Bar, Neo, Me etc. no matter which format they provide me like bar, nEO, ME and want to persist this value into $2 variable.

```
main.sh
echo "${2^}"

./main.sh me nEO --> NEO -expected is-> Neo
```

For which I used `${2^}` but was only successful with `bar` scenario

Comment: Why not transfer it to a normal shell variable, and then modify & use that? e.g. you could lowercase the whole thing, then uppercase the first letter like this: `name=${2,,}; name=${name^}` and then just use `"$name"` instead of `"$2"` in the rest of the script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I get your point. But I was looking for a way through which I can either do both `,,` and `^` inside `${}` or channel final value of `$name -> $2`

Comment: @KNDheeraj You can't do both `,,` and `^` in a single step, you'd have to use an external tool (and it'd be messy there). Replacing `$2` is also possible, but also messy (you have to replace *all* of the arguments at once with `set`, but replace all but `$2` with their original values). You're really better off adjusting to what bash can do easily. Besides, named variables are easier to keep straight than argument numbers; many people like to copy the args into named variables just so it's easier remember which is which.

Comment: @GordonDavisson your are right, I didn't realise it but using set is ruining all my special variables. I was just looking for possibilities, so I believe I must go with `$name` approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash:

```
declare -c string="nEO"
echo "$string"
```

This converts the first character to uppercase and all others to lowercase.

Output:

```
Neo
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Cyrus' solution, but here's an alternative.

```
a=nEO
b=${a,,}   # neo
echo ${b^} # Neo
```